# Capturar hora de base de datos

Tags: c#

Tengo un formulario que guarda hora Inicio y hora fin

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto inserta la hora que yo quiera en la base de datos, inserta correctamente 
pero a la hora de editar esta hora es decir capturar la hora que guarde y mostrarla en la DateTimePiker  me sale el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el código

```
    private void BtnEditarForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
                {
                    FormAddActividad frm = new FormAddActividad
                    {
                        operacion = "Editar"
                    };
                    frm.dateHInicio.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["HoraInicio"].Value);
                    frm.dateHFin.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["HoraFin"].Value);
                    frm.ShowDialog();
                    ListarActividad();
                }
                else MessageBox.Show("Debe seleccionar una fila ");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

No puedes convertir directamente un timespan a un datetime, una forma posible es asignar a una fecha esa hora y luego asignarlo al control

```
var ts = (TimeSpan)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["HoraFin"].Value;
var dt = new DateTime(1900, 01, 01) + ts;

... asignar esa fecha a control ...
```

Comment: Pero yo no lo tengo como TimeSpan no entiendo muy bien